# Display a nodes fields using a custom page display template in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I have the custom page diplay template working page--press.tpl.php however I cant seem to access the nodes field data.

This does not work

field_pr_link[$noderr->language][0]['value']; 
print($noderr);
?>

however I can print_r $node just fine and see my field data I just cant get to it.

Answer (score 1):

Install Drupal's [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module and use it to print the $node object to see what other information you have access to.  Once devel is installed, insert `dpm($node)` in your code to print out the node and you'll see what you can access in the node.

http://blog.anselmbradford.com/2009/03/14/2-invaluable-drupal-development-tips-list-all-available-variables-and-backtrace-a-page/ has some illustrations of what the devel print out on the page would look like.

Comment: I installed Devel and will figure out why dpm is not returning anything now even though I can print_r $node fine and I can $node->nid fine. Without Devel do you know how I can do this? $node->field_pr_link. field_pr_link is a cck feild. Accessing the node object is still a mystery to me.